# Tomato - How should I approach permitting internet access ONLY via OpenVPN?

Tags: openvpn, tomato

I can think of a whole lot of ways to accomplish this, but what would be the **simplest** and **least error-prone** way to configure a Tomato router with an OpenVPN client profile to permit internet access ONLY via the VPN?

Note that checking "Redirect Internet traffic" (redirect-gateway def1) is part of the solution but NOT a complete solution, as internet access would be available when the VPN is down.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the use of iptables. The archlinux forum has a good writeup on how this is done. See https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=192218 or perhaps even better the airvpn forum posting https://airvpn.org/topic/9920-airvpn-with-tomato-shibby-router/. Will likely need to adapt to some degree. In the first case, in short it drops all outgoing by default and then allows outgoing on local area network and vpn. In the 2nd case, addressed by combination of forwarding and dropping. Doing a search for something like "block vpn disconnects iptables" or "vpn disconnect iptables tomato" will bring up similar scripts.

Under tomato such scripts can be inserted via the GUI through Administration->Scripts->Firewall.